# Navbar collapsing wont work with block content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Couldn't find any reasons why the collapse function won't work when I have the block content in html.

Anyone know why it won't work and how I can fix it?

```
<div class="masthead">
<!--<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="base_navbar">-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#base_header" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="base_header">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="navbar_text">
                <li><a href="#" id="home"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="food"><h3>food</h3></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="contakt"><h3>Contact</h3></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
<div id="base_background-block">
    <div id="base_text-block">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

As of now I can only toggle the collapse to open but I can't close it. So how can I also make the navbar "close"-able?

Comment: For starters, there is a closing `</nav>`, but no opening `<nav>`. Double check the HTML first

Comment: Is Your console clear from errors? Have You add jquerry-min to <head>?

Comment: Are you kidding us. Your code is working just fine:https://fiddle.jshell.net/vd7useay/

Comment: Fixed everything you guys pointed out and still not working. Aakash Thakur did you even try with the block content? NO, so are you kidding me?

Comment: Somehow when I remove the "block content"-part the collapse works but I need the stuff included in there..

Comment: Can you post your page pls? Maybe you load something more in your head and block the JS.

Comment: It's a schoolproject and it's only local (My school is cheap and don't wanna pay for servers...)

Comment: @Fourierstudent You should have provide your code on JSFiddle or the likes of it,  so we can see and find solution easily.

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution I did that but the result isn't good... On JSFiddle the collapsing works but I think that's because the "{% block content %}{% endblock %}" doesn't work properly (on JSFiddle). But on LocalHost it interrupts the collapsing somehow.

What I don't understand is why it only stops the hiding function of collapse